# tring to learn oop and need help understanding how to pass multiple variables to function/methods

Tags: php, oop

im new to oop and i would like to know how to pass multiple variables/properties to a function within a class or methods.  for example im trying to convert this code below to oop please dont just convert it for me id like to know how to pass multiple properties instead of setting multiple globals. should i do it with the constructor or just pass it via function eg _comm($var1,$var2,$var3,$var3) or like this? "new comm_class($var1,$var2,$var3,$var3);"

```
            function _comm($vresults) {

            global $conn;
            global $varfightno;
            global $p_comm;
            global $b_comm;
            global $s_comm;
            global $vtagid;
            global $aid;


            $fdetails   = $conn->prepare("select  distinct(fldusrcd) as vuser from tblplyrbetlisttemp where fldarenaid= ?");
            $fdetails->execute([$aid]);
            $row_rscoll = $fdetails->fetch();

            if ($fdetails->rowCount() > 0) {

                do {

                    $varuserid = $row_rscoll['vuser'];
                    $vtrandate = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
                    $T0        = 0;

                    if ($vresults == 'BANKER') {

                        $varodd = 'fldB0price';
                        $win_comm = $b_comm;

                    }

                    if ($vresults == 'PLAYER') {

                        $varodd = 'fldP0price';
                        $win_comm = $p_comm;
                    }

                    $sel_bet = $conn->prepare("select SUM({$varodd}),SUM(fldT0),SUM(fldPP0),SUM(fldBP0),SUM(fldAP0) FROM tblplyrbetlisttemp where  fldarenaid = ? and fldusrcd = ?");
                    $sel_bet->execute([$aid,$varuserid]);
                    $fetch_bet = $sel_bet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

                    if ($sel_bet->rowCount() > 0) {

                        $sel_bet = null;

                            $OC = ($win_comm * $fetch_bet[0]) + 0;
                            $T0 = $fetch_bet[1] + 0;
                            $PP0 = $fetch_bet[2] + 0;
                            $BP0 = $fetch_bet[3] + 0;
                            $AP0 = $fetch_bet[4] + 0;


                        $sel_tranno    = $conn->prepare("select max(fldtranno) from tblcollplasada where fldarenaid= ?");
                        $sel_tranno->execute([$aid]);
                        $vtranno       = $sel_tranno->fetchColumn() + 1;
                        $sel_tranno    = null;

                        $params        = array(
                            $vtagid,
                            $vtranno,
                            $varfightno,
                            $vtrandate,
                            $varuserid,
                            $vresults,
                            $win_comm,
                            $s_comm,
                            $OC,
                            $T0,
                            $PP0,
                            $BP0,
                            $AP0,
                            $aid,
                        );
                        $place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));

                        $ins           = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tblcollplasada(fldtag,fldtranno,fldfightno,fldtrandate,fldusrcd,fldwinner,fldpercomm,sys_comm,fld1010,fldD7,fldPP0,fldBP0,fldAP0,fldarenaid) VALUES({$place_holders})");
                        $ins->execute($params);
                        $ins = null;

                    }

                } while ($row_rscoll = $fdetails->fetch());

            }

        }
```

Comment: Either way would be fine. It really depends on what the class is to be used for, and do these data items get used by more than one method. If they are used in more than one of the classes methods passing on the `__construct()` might make more sense

Answer (score 0):

```
function test($one, $two, $three){}
test($one, $two, $three);
```

or

```
function test($vars){}
$vars = array('one' => $one, 'two' => $two, 'three' => $three);
test($vars);
```

These will both pass the variables into the function, from there you can use them however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If the varible is used in multiple functions of the same class passing it in via the `__construct()` is quite an acceptable way.

For example `global $conn;` could be passed in like so:

```
class ClassName
{
    protected $conn = null;

    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn
    }
}
```

This is better, but what's even better is type hinting:

```
class ClassName
{
    protected $conn = null;

    public function __construct(PDO $conn) // Assuming it's PDO here 
    {
        $this->conn = $conn
    }
}
```

---

I never recommend passing in arguments to the construct via an array. For example `__construct(['conn' => $conn ...]` as you deprive yourself of autocomplete in IDEs and it makes tracking of the arguments harder.

---

It's more than acceptable to pass 3-4 arguments to a function, more than that usually means that the function is doing way too many things. Of course this is all subjective and should never be taken as "set in stone". It's just something to think about.